# How to auto-complete JSON syntax strings?

Tags: compilation, antlr4, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

Specifically, it is required that given the string above, the output will be the next character set that matches the JSON syntax.

Example 1: All Possible Next Tokens for the empty text ("") is

['{', '[', '"', '0', /[1-9]/, '-', 't', 'f', 'n']

Where /[1-9]/ denotes a rule that matches a single character.

Example 2: The next character set for ´{ "key"´ above is

[':', ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n']

Example 3: The next character set of 0 above is null, which means that the EOF of the JSON has been reached, since a number starting with 0 can only be 0.

JSON syntax can be found at JSON.org. I've been trying to figure this out for 4 days, and I've deleted most of the code I've written, but I can't get it to work.

Tag: grammar, LL grammar, context-independent grammar, compilation principle

I tried Antlr4's API and its Auto Complete Core and found that it makes errors and misses possible characters.

Comment: What "Auto Complete Core"? Can you include the code you've tried and explain the "errors" you are getting?